# Unknown error in Spotify auth flow SDK

Tags: ios, swift, sdk, spotify

When I try and authenticate using the Safari-flow for Spotify in the iOS SDK, all goes well. However, when I install the Spotify app, then it redirects me directly to the app and back, returning this error:

`Error Domain=com.spotify.auth Code=0 "unknown_error" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=unknown_error}`.

Does anyone know what this means?

Answer (score 0):

This happens intermittently when you authenticate a user who has the Spotify client installed (i.e. you don't use the web view). Its a known bug that Spotify plans to address in an upcoming release of their app.  https://github.com/spotify/ios-sdk/issues/650#issuecomment-240512711

Comment: Yeah, I had seen that. I'm glad it's on their issues list. Thanks!